# CakePHP 3 Breadcrumbs - Call to a member function add() on boolean

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Yet another question due to the poor Cake 3 documentation...

This time it's [Breadcrumbs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/breadcrumbs.html). So I have the following in a Controller:

```
use Cake\View\Helper\BreadcrumbsHelper;

class ProductsController extends AppController
{

    public function browse()
    {
        $this->Breadcrumbs->add('Products',
        ['controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'index']);
    }

}
```

Which gives the following error:

**Call to a member function `add()` on boolean**

Why does this not work? I'm getting sick of posting these but whenever I try and use exact examples from Cake's own documentation, it produces error messages! Could be that I've specified this in the "wrong" place, but again, the documentation doesn't say where this goes anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->Breadcrumbs->add('Products',
    ['controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'index']);
```

Place that in your template file.

And then:

```
echo $this->Breadcrumbs->render();
```

Comment: Thanks. Of course the documentation fails to make clear *where* each bit of code goes. So much of the Cake 3.x docs are like that though. It's like, oh here's a bit of PHP, we'll leave you to decide where that might go... Useless.

Comment: @Andy A helpers sole purpose is to be used in the view/presentation layer. The docs definitely could be more clear in some places, but please don't blame everything on them. It sounds like you didn't read the view/helper section, and just started somewhere in the middle of a subsection, and that won't work out well with any documentation whatsoever.

Comment: @ndm fair enough, but I've used Cake since 2009 and if I'm struggling to find things in the documentation then not sure how someone new to it would get on. In the docs for 2.x most of the code samples had a comment to say which file the code should be put in (e.g. `// In app/View/Foo/bar.ctp`) etc. In the ones for 3.x they have done that but not in all places and it's very confusing. I feel the documentation for 3.x is letting it down which is why I get frustrated with using it. I feel to some extent that this is why some other PHP frameworks have surpassed Cake now.

Comment: The documentation, like the code, is open source, so when you find things like this, you can do pull requests to update it.